# find the limit of the following expression

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f\left(x\right)=\left(x^{2}+1\right)e^{x}$.

Find the following:$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}n\int_{0}^{1}\left(f\left(\frac{x^{2}}{n}\right)-1\right)\,dx$$

I dont know if L'Hopital's Rule may be used and tried using Integral Mean Value Theorem, but I cannot solve it! Any help?

Comment: The integrand is a polynomial times $e^x$, right? did you integrate by parts?

Comment: The result is $2/3$.

Comment: Whoops, no, the integrand is a polynomial times $e^{x^2/n}$.  Big difference when integrating!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the substitution $u = x/\sqrt{n}$ we write

$$n\int_0^1 \left(f\left(\frac{x^2}{n}\right) - 1\right)\, dx = n^{3/2}\int_0^{1/\sqrt{n}} (f(u^2) - 1)\, du.$$

Now

\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{3/2}\int_0^{1/\sqrt{n}} (f(u^2) - 1)\, du &= \lim_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{\int_0^h (f(u^2) - 1)\, du}{h^3} \quad (\text{letting $h = 1/\sqrt{n}$})\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0^{+}} \frac{f(h^2) - 1}{3h^2} \quad (\text{by L'hospital's rule})\\
&= \lim_{t\to 0^{+}} \frac{f(t) - f(0)}{3t} \quad (\text{letting $t = h^2$})\\
&= \frac{1}{3}f'(0).
\end{align}

So $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\int_0^1 \left(f\left(\frac{x^2}{n}\right) - 1\right)\, dx = \frac{f'(0)}{3}.$$

Comment: wow I would never have realised of that substitution! Keen eye! Many thanks!!!

Comment: What condition on $f$ will ensure existence of the limit. For example, if $f(x) = 0$, the integral is $-1$ so the limit does not exist, but $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: @marty I wasn't using a general $f$, but $f(x) = (x^2 + 1)e^x$. The limit has indeterminate form $0/0$, and $\lim_{h\to 0^{+}} \frac{f(h^2)-1}{3h^2}$ exists since $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f(0) = 1$. So I may apply L'hospital's rule in this case.

Comment: So f(0) = 1 is necessary. Looks like $f(1+h) = 1+O(h)$ might be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general technique to deal with such problems where the integrand is explicitly known. The way I presented it is not considered mathematically rigorous because it makes no sense to integrate a set, but the idea is to show that the integrand must actually be some **function in some class**, and since we already knew that it was integrable we can proceed to find the class of possible values of the integral. I chose this presentation to make the intuition clear.

Let $[c] = \{ x : |x| \le |c| \}$.

As $n \to \infty$:

Let $a > 0$ such that $\exp(\frac{x^{2}}{n}) \in 1+\frac{x^{2}}{n}+[a]\frac{x^{4}}{n^2}$ for any $x \in [0,1]$.

$n\int_{0}^{1}\left((\frac{x^4}{n^2}+1)\exp(\frac{x^{2}}{n})-1\right) dx$

$\in n\int_{0}^{1}\left((\frac{x^4}{n^2}+1)(1+\frac{x^{2}}{n}+[a]\frac{x^{4}}{n^2})-1\right) dx$

$\subseteq n\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{n}x^2+[b]\frac{1}{n^2}\right) dx$ for some $b > 0$ [because $x^4,x^6,x^8 \in [0,1]$ and $\frac{1}{n^3},\frac{1}{n^4} \in [1]\frac{1}{n^2}$]

$\subseteq \int_{0}^{1}x^2\ dx+[b]\frac{1}{n} \to \frac{1}{3}$

Note that this relied on the first-order term (in $n$) in the integrand to be $O(\frac{1}{n})$, in the same way that kobe's answer used L'Hopital's rule only on an indeterminate form. Note also that this method works even for non-differentiable integrands that have asymptotic expansions.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n \int_0^1 \left[f\left(\frac{x^2}{n}\right) -1\right]\,dx 
= \lim_{n\to\infty} n \int_0^1 \left[\left(\frac{x^4}{n^2} + 1\right)e^{x^2/n} - 1\right]\,dx
$$
You can expand the exponential as a Taylor series:
\begin{align*}
n\int_0^1 \left[\left(\frac{x^4}{n^2} + 1\right)e^{x^2/n} - 1\right]\,dx
&= n\int_0^1 \Biggl[\frac{x^4}{n^2}\left\{1 + \frac{x^2}{n} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{x^4}{n^2} + \frac{1}{3!}\frac{x^6}{n^3}+\cdots\right\} \\
&\qquad\qquad+1\left\{\color{red}{1} + \color{green}{\frac{x^2}{n}} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{x^4}{n^2} + \frac{1}{3!}\frac{x^6}{n^3}+\cdots\right\} \\
&\qquad\qquad\color{red}{-1}\Biggr]\,dx\\
&= n\int_0^1\left[\color{green}{\frac{x^2}{n}} 
+ \frac{3}{2}\frac{x^4}{n^2}
+ \frac{7}{6}\frac{x^6}{n^3} + \cdots
\right],dx
\end{align*}
Everything in the integrand after the first term is a multiple of $\frac{1}{n^2}$, so even after multiplying by $n$, the integrals will vanish as $n\to\infty$.  So the limit is
$
    \int_0^1 x^2\,dx = \frac{1}{3}
$.